# A left Artinian ring that is also a right Noetherian ring 

Tags: artin-ring

I am having trouble showing that a ring which is left Artinian and right Noetherian is right Artinian.

Comment: Elohemahab: are you sure this stuff holds for noncommutative rings?

Comment: For the title: Since [DCC] is stronger than ACC, a left (right) Artinian ring is also a left (right) Noetherian ring. Hence, you can take; for instance, rings for which left and right coincides such as  finite rings and commutative rings. 

Comment: That is another homework problem. Voted to close. 

Comment: Hint: Consider the $J$-adic filtration on the ring $A$, where $J$ is the Jacobson radical, and apply Artin-Wedderburn to $A/J$.